# Which method does the Stack Exchange iOS app use to store login info on the device?

Tags: support, ios-app

After logging into my Stack Exchange account via the iOS app and removing it, upon reinstalling the app from the App Store and launching it for the first time I am automatically logged in. Which method does the app use to store this login info - is it stored via iCloud, the device Keychain, or something else entirely?